# Can we use google stun server (default for nodejs webrtc.io-client) for commercial apps?

Tags: webrtc, stun

https://npmjs.org/package/webrtc.io-client says:

> Usage
>
> ```
> rtc.createStream({"video": true, "audio":true}, function(stream){
>   // get local stream for manipulation
> }
> rtc.connect('ws://yourserveraddress:8001', optionalRoom);
> //
> ```
>
> then a bunch of callbacks are available
>
> **You can set the STUN server by calling rtc.SERVER = "STUN
>   stun.l.google.com:19302" and set your server. The default STUN server**
>   used by the library is one from google.

Can I use the same STUN server for my commercial app too?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Can you?

Yes.

### Should you?

No.

Using any third party without an agreement is dangerous and could leave you burnt in the future.

### Some history:

Google has previously issued [after the fact API restrictions/price changes](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2011/10/27/google_maps_api_no_longer_free/) that left a lot of people with a broken business model.